# TreeView with CheckBoxes in c#

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a tree view with checkboxes in c#, I want that when the user checks one node all the nodes that there are on the levels below automatic checked also.
Does anyone know about way to do that without run with recorsive fnction on all the tree each time that the user checks some node?

Thanks

//this function returns the treeView.

```
   public TreeView GetTreeView()
    {

        getSubject();
        // fill the treeview with all subjects.
        foreach (Subject subject in subjects)
        {
            //for each root subject fill all the his children.
            if (subject.subjestId == subject.parentSubject)
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(subject.subjectString, subject.subjestId, subject.subjestId);
                addChild(node, subject.subjestId);
                tv.Nodes.Add(node);
            }
        }
        return tv;
    }
   // for each subject return sub subjects.
   private void addChild(TreeNode node, int parentId)
    {
        foreach (Subject subject in subjects)
        {
            if (subject.parentSubject == parentId && subject.parentSubject != subject.subjestId)
            {
                TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(subject.subjectString, subject.subjestId, subject.subjestId);
                addChild(childNode, subject.subjestId);
                node.Nodes.Add(childNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Kiquenet - that the question is lacking the GUI platform (WinForms, WPF and ASP.NET all have their own, different, TreeViews)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Recursion.  Like this:

```
    bool busy = false;

    private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) {
        if (busy) return;
        busy = true;
        try {
            checkNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
        }
        finally {
            busy = false;
        }
    }

    private void checkNodes(TreeNode node, bool check) {
        foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes) {
            child.Checked = check;
            checkNodes(child, check);
        }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the `busy` flag ? Could it be useful in other part of the code ? :)

Comment: @dig, because assigning child.Checked will cause the AfterCheck event to run again.  That won't work out well.

Comment: oh, of course ! Sorry but I didn't notice the `if(busy) return;` line... I'm very distracted (or perhaps a bit sleepy) ! :P

Comment: Rather than using a global bool switch, you can ignore 'AfterCheck's being fired by checking the e.Action property, if it is 'Unknown' then the event was fired by code rather than user.

Comment: That's fairly troublesome, you'd normally want the TV consistent as well when it is code that sets a checkbox value.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) {
  foreach (TreeNode child in e.Node.Nodes) {
    child.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a better solution

```
private void trvMenuList_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            SetChildrenChecked(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);

        }

  private void SetChildrenChecked(TreeNode treeNode, bool checkedState)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode item in treeNode.Nodes)
            {
                if (item.Checked != checkedState)
                {
                    item.Checked = checkedState;
                }
                SetChildrenChecked(item, item.Checked);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a number of the answers state, create a recursive 'set checked to children' function, then call it AfterCheck on the tree.

The framework unfortunately gives you a call back to AfterCheck even if you set the check value in code, and although this may not be noticeable in small trees adds a massive amount of exponential extra work for your app to do.  To avoid it, filter AfterCheck to only fire your new function if it has been triggered by user.

```
    private void tree_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
        {
            SetChildrenChecked(e.Node);
        }
    }

    private void SetChildrenChecked(TreeNode treeNode)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode item in treeNode.Nodes)
        {
            if (item.Checked != treeNode.Checked)
            {
                item.Checked = treeNode.Checked;
            }

            if (item.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                SetChildrenChecked(item);
            }                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I expanded on the answer a little; by updating the parent as well.  [The `DisplayException` method inside the catch is just a popup window that I always use; you can do your own]

```
    private bool _busy = false;  

    private void treeViewPassFail_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_busy)
            {
                return;
            }

            _busy = true;

            CheckNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);

            CheckParent(e.Node.Parent);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayException(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            _busy = false;
        }
    }

    private void CheckNodes(TreeNode node, bool check)
    {
        foreach(TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
        {
            child.Checked = check;
            CheckNodes(child, check);
        }
    }

    private void CheckParent(TreeNode parent)
    {
        if (parent != null)
        {
            bool allChecked = true;

            foreach (TreeNode node in parent.Nodes)
            {
                allChecked &= node.Checked;
            }

            parent.Checked = allChecked;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it in WinForms then I think you have to do it manually by recursion - I don't know any better way.