# How to uncheck folders in KML file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, kml, kmz

i have made `visibility` to 0 but no luck at all,still loading all data when i load with Google Earth .How to uncheck all folders and inside items so user can select which ever required in later.i am creating KML through c# and i am posting small part of big KML file which i am converting in to `KMZ`.What is wrong in following `kml` snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<kml:kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:json="http://www.w3.org/2005/Json">

  <kml:Folder>

    <kml:visibility>0</kml:visibility>

    <kml:name>Test</kml:name>

    <kml:open>1</kml:open>

    <kml:Folder>

      <kml:visibility>0</kml:visibility>

      <kml:name>2G</kml:name>

      <kml:open>1</kml:open>

      <kml:Folder>

        <kml:visibility>0</kml:visibility>

        <kml:name>Icro</kml:name>

        <kml:Folder>

          <kml:visibility>0</kml:visibility>

          <kml:name>Working</kml:name>
        </kml:Folder>
      </kml:Folder>
    </kml:Folder>
  </kml:Folder>

  <kml:Folder>

    <kml:visibility>0</kml:visibility>

    <kml:name>3G</kml:name>

    <kml:open>1</kml:open>

    <kml:Folder>

      <kml:visibility>0</kml:visibility>

      <kml:name>Testro</kml:name>

      <kml:Folder>

        <kml:visibility>0</kml:visibility>

        <kml:name>Working</kml:name>

        <Document xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">

          <name>POINTS</name>
        </Document>
      </kml:Folder>
    </kml:Folder>
  </kml:Folder>
</kml:kml>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a "feature" in Google Earth that contradicts how the KML 2.2 spec describes data is visible by the visibility of parent folders.

The OGC KML 2.2 Standard states "in order for a Feature to be visible, the *kml:visibility* tag of all its ancestors shall also be set to 1 or true". This means that having visibility=0 on a parent folder should make all child placemarks contained within the folder not visible.

However, Google Earth implements visibility such that visibility on a child element overrides visibility on parent folders even if the visibility is not explicitly defined (by default visibility=1) and this violates the standard as stated above. This was reported as a [bug](https://code.google.com/archive/p/earth-issues/issues/435) in 2009 and described [here](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlErrata.html#visibility). Google responded to the issue as follows:

> “Visibility has always been overridden on the child element level, and
>   changing this would break existing code”

**This means all of the KML placemarks that want not to show at startup must explicitly have visibility 0 rather than just setting it once at the Folder/Document level**.